# Subscribe to event of an object which is not yet created?

Tags: c#, sql-server, events

Well I really doubt if this is possible, but maybe after all it maybe.
I want to subscribe to an event when my program initialize but the object will be created long after my form load. At the time of subscription, the object is null, but later its created. Is it possible to update that object so that the event will fire?

In the Form_Load, I subscribe like this

```
  this.mediaCenter.ItemManager.Root.SetProgressBar += (val) => 
        { 
             this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                this.progressBarControl1.Position = val;
            }));
        };
```

In Item Manager, the object is null during form load

```
   private ItemContainerRoot _myRoot;
        public ItemContainerRoot Root
        {
            get { return this._myRoot; }
        }
```

Later my Database will get the object

```
this._myRoot = context.GetTable<Item>().Single(a => a.Id == 0) as ItemContainerRoot;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

In Class Library notify when Root property changes and use the property (not the field) everywhere.

```
class ItemManager : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ItemContainerRoot _myRoot;
    public ItemContainerRoot Root
    {
        get { return _myRoot; }

        set
        {
            _myRoot = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Root");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In UI subscribe to the property changed event of the ItemManager after initialization:

```
ItemManager.PropertyChanged += (o, args) =>
{
     if (args.PropertyName == "Root" && ItemManager.Root != null)
     {
          ItemManager.Root.SetProgressBar += (val) =>
          {
               this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
               {
                    this.progressBarControl1.Position = val;
               }));
          };
     }
};
```

Comment: Thnaks for your response. The first part of the Code is on my UI form whilst the rest is on another class library. So progressBarControl1 is not in the class libraray.

Comment: @electricalbah You need some way of making one part visible to the other. I think you should make your library accessible to the UI and not the opposite. I mean you should not do `x = y` in your class library if `x` is in your UI. I'll post a workaround.

Comment: Thanks, thats really great to subscribe On propertyChange. But I have one concern, each time that property change, a new subscription is made. Should I be worried about memory or something? Do I need to unsubscribe if already subscribed?

Comment: @electricalbah I think you shouldn't be worried about memory because you are subscribing to a new `Root` instance. Just don't keep references to old `Root` instances.

Comment: @electricalbah NP. I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this properly you need to jump through a few hoops:

```
private Action _myRootDisconnect = null;
private object _myRootGate = new object();
private ItemContainerRoot _myRoot;
public ItemContainerRoot Root
{
    get { return _myRoot; }
    set
    {
        lock (_myRootGate)
        {
            Action<int> setProgressBar = val =>
            {
                this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    this.progressBarControl1.Position = val;
                }));
            };

            if (_myRootDisconnect != null)
            {
                _myRootDisconnect();
                _myRootDisconnect = null;
            }

            _myRoot = value;
            _myRoot.SetProgressBar += setProgressBar;

            _myRootDisconnect = () =>
            {
                _myRoot.SetProgressBar -= setProgressBar;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Basically this code is wiring up your event whenever you assign the instance to the property - not the field.

It's got a `lock` because you're obviously calling this code from another thread (but I don't know why).

It's also creating an `Action` called `_myRootDisconnect` to enable you to disconnect the event whenever you reassign `Root` (or when you are cleanly exiting your code.)